# Can't get the user email from user info when code executing in timer job

Tags: email, timer-jobs, user

```
SPList resourceList = SiteProvisioningProvider.GetListReference(web, "Lists/list");
                foreach (SPFieldUserValue admin in adminCollection)
                {
                    SPListItem resourceItem = resourceList.Items.Add();
                    string name = admin.User.Name;
                    resourceItem["FirstName"] = name.Split(' ')[0].ToString();
                    resourceItem["Email"] = admin.User.Email;//null
                    resourceItem.Update();
                    web.SiteGroups["Engagement Administrator"].AddUser(admin.User);
                }
                resourceList.Update();

Above code is returning email and name of the user infomation. The same methos is called when i click some button in sharepoint site and also timer job calling the same method. But nly in the timer job i am not getting any email id for any user in any domain. This is happening is production environment not with QA/DEV. What will be the issue?
```

Comment: your code run inside SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{ }); ??
and other thing is check in userprofile that email is added or not

Comment: yep, email added properly.same code work every where except it get called from the timmer job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find sharepoint all user from hidden list named **"User Information List"**.
and its url like this **"siturl/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx".** using this list you can fetch all email id of sharepoint users.

```
public string getEmail(string firstName,lastName)
{
string emailID = "";
 try
   {
     SPListItemCollection spListItemColl = Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList.Items;
     foreach (SPListItem item in spListItemColl)
     {
         //Checking for first and last name
      if (item["FirstName"] != null && (firstName.ToUpper() == item["FirstName"].ToString().ToUpper()) && item["LastName"] != null && (lastName.ToUpper() == item["LastName"].ToString().ToUpper()) && item["EMail"] != null)
      {
  emailID = item["EMail"].ToString();
   break;
      }
   }
 }
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
return emailID;
}
```

you can also see this link might be helpful for you: 
   http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this ans.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/0a51a562-ccf3-48be-b502-ba6a443f05b7/

Comment: this post talking about the the current user. my issue is with all the users.